# Install Error with Ves_Brand

Tags: magento2, module, admin-panel

I downloaded [Ves_Brand](http://www.venustheme.com/theme/ves-brand-2-0/). I installed the module by copying the *app* folder to my *app* folder of magento 2:

[image]
and ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade`; it worked.

[image]

But when I search in my magento admin the module is not there:

[image]

Is this the way that I should install Ves_Brand? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you purchased that extension with the same account which you configured in your Magento?

If you purchased that extension with another extension then it's not displayed in the admin section.

Comment: Thank you for your response  yes i use the same account and i just download for free